# Cordova plugin callback not being called (iOS)

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm developing a Cordova plugin for iOS. There's a method in my 'plugin.js' I call only once from my app (javascript) to start listening for callbacks from the native part. When calling this method, I'm storing the callbackId in the Objective-C class, and want to send the callback later on (multiple callbacks possible), so I use the stored callbackId to send the CDVPluginResult, and set 'keepCallback' to true. But callback never arrives in the 'plugin.js', therefor not in the app.

Objective-C Method 1 (that's the listener part):

```
- (void)listenForNews:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command
{
   self.storedCallbackId = command.callbackId;
   ...
```

Objective-C Method 2 (that's the method which is being called multiple times asynchronously)

```
- (void)onNewsReceived
{
   CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];
   [pluginResult setKeepCallbackAsBool:YES];
   [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:self.storedCallbackId];
```

I've already verified that the 'storedCallbackId' is properly stored and read.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I do something like the following [in my plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin/blob/master/src/ios/Diagnostic.m#L111) and it works, so give this a try:

```
- (void)listenForNews:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command
{
   self.storedCallbackId = command.callbackId;
   ...
   CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_NO_RESULT];
   [pluginResult setKeepCallback:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
   [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];


- (void)onNewsReceived
{
   CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];
   [pluginResult setKeepCallback:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
   [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:self.storedCallbackId];
```

Comment: Thanks @DaveAlden. We could fix the issue. At the end it was a problem of having multiple instances of the plugin class, which caused Cordova to loose the callback (of course).

Comment: Thank you! I was able to implement this in a Swift plugin I've been working on. This was the last little piece I needed to get it to work! I appreciate you.

Comment: I implemented the same, but the callback reached .js file only for the first time. For the next delegate method calls, it never called again. Please help.